# Why doesn't Hibernate fully resolve my object when returning it from a @Transactional method (Spring boot)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a method that contains this line in my serviceImpl.java class:

`Device device = getDevice(nbr);`

And in the same class is the method:

```
 @Transactional(transactionManager = JpaConfigCbOrg.TX_MGR)
    private Device getDevice(Long nbr)
    {

        Device device = deviceRepository.findById(nbr).get();
        return device;

    }
```

When I get the device from the getDevice method, the Device object has not been fully resolved but still has the object proxies for its fields that are objects even though I have annotated the getDevice method with @Transactional.

For instance, there is a property on the Device object called DeviceModel that is declared like this:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "model_nbr", referencedColumnName = "model_nbr"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "dev_type", referencedColumnName = "dev_type")
    })
    private DeviceModel          model;
```

But when I look at the Device object after returning it from this @Transactional method, I don't see the actual DeviceModel property but an object proxy.

Why is this happening?  What am I missing about hibernate and transactions that leads me to believe this method should return the full object?

Comment: You have set your `model` to be lazily loaded. Yet, you do not call any getter or anything else to actually load it. Whether this is loaded in a transactional way, is not relevant here.

Comment: "What am I missing about hibernate and transactions". Probably a lot. Even fully understanding transactions isn't given, and Hibernate is probably the same magnitude of complexity. But at least this question is Hibernate-only, as Karthik pointed out that the transaction annotation is not processed, and it's not needed either (`deviceRepository` will start its own transaction).

Answer (score 2):

Issue 1:
`@Transactional` doesn't have any effect on private methods unless you youse aop based proxy. You also don't need transactional property for get operations as you don't control the commit or flush.

Issue 2:
Objects declared lazy will have proxy until you invoke the greeter on the lazy object. Try `device.getModel()` and check object.

Comment: Good catch on the private method.